# How to convert Strings in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, swift-string

I've two cases where I need to convert strings to different formats.

for ex:

```
case 1:
  string inputs: abc, xyz, mno, & llr   // All Strings from a dictionary
  output: ["abc","xyz", "mno", "llr"]  //I need to get the String array like this.
```

But when I use this code:

```
 var stringBuilder:[String] = [];
 for i in 0..<4 {
   stringBuilder.append("abc"); //Appends all four Strings from a Dictionary
 }

print(stringBuilder); //Output is 0: abc, 1:xyz like that, how to get desired format of that array like ["abc", "xyz"];
```

Real usage:

```
let arr = Array(stringReturn.values);
//print(arr)  // Great, it prints ["abc","xyz"];
let context = JSContext()
context?.evaluateScript(stringBuilder)   
let testFunction = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("KK")
let result = testFunction?.call(withArguments:arr); // Here when I debugger enabled array is passed to call() like 0:"abc" 1:"xyz". where as it should be passed as above print.
```

Secondly how to replace escape chars in swift: I used "\" in `replaceOccurances(of:"\\'" with:"'");` but its unchanged. why and how to escape that sequnce.

```
case 2:
  string input: \'abc\'
  output: 'abc'
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to contain the definition of your dictionary?

Comment: var stringReturn:Dictionary = Dictionary<String,Any>(); is the definition.

Comment: even [String:Any] is also printing the same na

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all values of your dictionary as an array you can use the `values` property of the dictionary:

```
let dictionary: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
    "key_a": "value_a",
    "key_b": "value_b",
    "key_c": "value_c",
    "key_d": "value_d",
    "key_e": 3
]

let values = Array(dictionary.values)
// values: ["value_a", "value_b", "value_c", "value_d", 3]
```

With `filter` you can ignore all values of your dictionary that are not of type `String`:

```
let stringValues = values.filter({ $0 is String }) as! [String]
// stringValues: ["value_a", "value_b", "value_c", "value_d"]
```

With map you can transform the values of `stringValues` and apply your `replacingOccurrences` function:

```
let adjustedValues = stringValues.map({ $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "value_", with: "") })
// adjustedValues: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: You output is like this:  LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<String, Any>, Any>(_base: ["key_a": "value_a", "key_b": "value_b"]

Comment: Well strange. I tested my code against Swift 3.2 and Swift 4 before posting. Maybe you are missing some information from your setup?

Comment: When I print the values its printed ["abc", "xyz"] but when I pass it like find(values) then after hitting debug point, it shows like 0:abc, 1:xyz

Comment: That is because the value at index 0 has the value `abc` and the value at index 1 has `xyz` I don't see the problem here. Maybe you can tell us more what you are trying to accomplish by extending your question.

Comment: see updated question. There call() need an array like ["xyz","abc"]

Comment: What the code above returns is an array of strings: `[String]` so it should work. You can simply try by just calling `let result = testFunction?.call(withArguments: ["xyz","abc"])` If that does not work `call` does not expect `[String]`

Answer (score 0):

**case 1:**
 I have Implemented this solutions, Hope this will solve your problem

```
   let dict: [String: String] = ["0": "Abc", "1": "CDF", "2": "GHJ"]                
   var array: [String] = []

for (k, v) in dict.enumerated() {
    print(k)
    print(v.value)
    array.append(v.value)  
}
print(array)
```

**case 2:**

```
    var str = "\'abc\'"
    print(str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\'", with: ""))
```

Comment: I need a array of format ["abc","xyz","mno"] where in your code will produce this.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I already did what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like this? For part 1 of the question that is:

```
var stringReturn: Dictionary = Dictionary<String,Any>()
stringReturn = ["0": "abc","1": "def","2": "ghi"]
print(stringReturn)

var stringBuilder = [String]()
for i in stringReturn {
  stringBuilder.append(String(describing: i.value))
}
print(stringBuilder)
```

Also, part 2 seems to be trivial unless I'm not mistaken

```
var escaped: String = "\'abc\'"
print(escaped)
```